# Sharepoint-Office Web Apps Server error on New-SPWOPIBinding -All:$

Tags: office-web-apps, owa

I am trying to bind my SharePoint 2013 to Office Web Apps Server.

The bind works with:

```
New-SPWOPIBinding -ServerName MyOfficeWebAppsServer
```

but it doesn't  with

```
New-SPWOPIBinding -ServerName MyOfficeWebAppsServer.mydomain
```

MyOfficeWebAppsServer.mydomain.it and responds to

```
https://MyOfficeWebAppsServer.mydomain/hosting/discovery
```

Is there anyting I could to make it work with  mydomain as well?

**EDIT:**
I forgot the error:

```
WARNING: The server did not respond. Trying again (attempt 1 of 5).
WARNING: The server did not respond. Trying again (attempt 2 of 5).
WARNING: The server did not respond. Trying again (attempt 3 of 5).
WARNING: The server did not respond. Trying again (attempt 4 of 5).
WARNING: The server did not respond. Trying again (attempt 5 of 5).
New-SPWOPIBinding : Sorry, we have encountered an error and New-SPWOPIBinding
has failed. If you are using a server configured with HTTP, you must include
the -AllowHTTP parameter.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-SPWOPIBinding -ServerName MyOfficeWebAppsServer.mydomain
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Microsoft.Share...tNewWOPIBinding
   :SPCmdletNewWOPIBinding) [New-SPWOPIBinding], SPCmdletException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletNewWOPIB
   inding
```

Comment: not working means...any error?

Comment: I have the same problem... My SharePoint farm is based on Azure, with 4 servers...AD / SQL / SP 2013sp1 / Owa2013sp1.
I tried with http and HTTPS (certificates generated by ADCS).
Have you any suggestion ?

Comment: #Fabrice Martin check my comments below. Maybe it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How did you setup your web app farm?  If you didn't use the FQDN that is why you can't connect over it.  Also check the zone bindings when you bind to SharePoint and make sure you are pointing at the URL where you will access web app farm.

Comment: I used New-OfficeWebAppsFarm -InternalURL https://MyOfficeWebAppsServer -ExternalURL https://MyOfficeWebAppsServer.mydomain / -CertificateName “Webapp” . Could you guide me through the process ?

Comment: #Jesus Shelby how to check the  zone bindings you mentioned?

Comment: Get-SPWOPIZone  - this will tell you the zone that SharePoint is using to connect to your OWA servers.  Get-SPWOPIBinding - this will show all the associations and Zone/Urls configured that SharePoint detected.  Make sure you are working with the intended zone that you have configured on the OWA server.

Comment: Ok, I had Set-SPWOPIZone -zone "internal-https" and then I managed to bind it. It was "external-https"

Answer (score 0):

Add this switch at the end of your command `-AllowHTTP`.  It worked for me.

Comment: Please consider adding some more explanation.

Comment: He say about configuring web app server without using https . It will resolve current problem, but it is not recomended to production environment.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue where the binding worked fine for one environment and it gave error on the second.

Just verify that Excel service and Secure Store service is running on the environment. In my case Secure store service was not running on any server in the Farm. Once I started it on the same server where Excel service was running, the issue got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I installed 4 servers on my domain.

- First one is for Active directory named "ZARD.shemshal"
- Second one is SQL server 2014 named "SQL.ZARD.shemshal"
- Third one is for SharePoint 2019 named "Sharepoint.ZARD.shemshal"
- Last one is for office online named "Office.ZARD.shemshal".

Now SharePoint is connected to SQL server and everything is working fine. Also I setup and config the office online with no error. But when I try to run  `"New-SPWOPIBinding -ServerName office -AllowHTTP" on sharepoint 2019 management shell`, It bring this error :
`New-SPWOPIBinding : Login failed for user 'SQL\Administrator'`.
At line:1 char:2
+

```
 New-SPWOPIBinding -ServerName office -AllowHTTP
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...tNewWOPIBinding:SPCmdletNewWOPIBinding) [New-SPWOPIBindi
   ng], SqlException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletNewWOPIBinding
```

My domain is ZARD.shemshal and my admin user is ZARD\administrator. I don't know why it's trying to login with SQL\Administrator . Is there anyone know how I can fix this problem?
Thanks in advance.